# Jenkins Pipeline project can't when on branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I want to use `when` on `branch` condition. The Jenkinsfile is like this

```
 stages{
        stage('Checkout project branch master'){
            steps{             
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'credential', keyFileVariable: 'CREDENTIAL')]) {}
                git branch: 'develop', credentialsId: 'credential', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:user/demopipelinejenkinsfile.git'
            }
        }   
        stage('develop'){
             steps {
                   echo 'on branch develop`
             }
        }
        stage('any_branch'){                  
             environment {
                   GIT_BRANCH = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
                   }
             steps{
                   echo "${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
                  }
        }
 }
```

The console output shows that the stage `develop` is skipped due to condition. However, the last stage still echoes the current branch is "develop"

**Question**
How to use `when` with `branch` in **Pipeline** project (not **Multibranch** project)

Comment: Can you provide the exact output of your error when running the pipeline?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you are using declarative pipelines, is that correct?

Comment: Your jenkinsfile stage `develop` doesn't have a when condition as seen above ? Are you able to provide the when condition you are using ? You can use something like `when { branch 'develop' }`

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to go:

```
stage('Deploy'){
  when {
    expression {env.GIT_BRANCH == 'origin/master'}
  }
  steps {
    ....
   }
}
```

Take care, this is only working with the declarative syntax.

The environment step is used to "set up the environment" meaning this is the place to declare environmental variables.

Also, in my case I did not declare the GIT_BRANCH var myself. But jenkins provides it as an environmental (therefore "env.GIT_BRANCH") variable if you did "checkout scm" to checkout your repository. If you want to check all the available env vars, do this as a step: `sh 'printenv'`

check out this article for more info: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/